# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'submit' error in sencha touch 2.1

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I have a problem with submitting this form. when i click submit button it shows 
 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'submit' error .

```
submitcontactform :function()
    {

        var form= this.getLoginform();
        form.submit({
            url:'contact.php'
        });
    }
```

thanks in advance

edit:

my login.js

```
Ext.define('sencha.view.Login',{
            extend:'Ext.Panel',
            xtype:'LoginPanel',
            id:'loginform',
            config:{
                title:'LoginForm',
                items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'emailfield',
                            name : 'email',
                            label: 'Email'

                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'passwordfield',
                            name : 'password',
                            label: 'Password'

                        },
                        {   
                            xtype:'button',
                            text:'Submit',
                            ui:'confirm',
                            action:'submitForm'

                       }
                        ]
            }


});
```

my controller

```
Ext.define('sencha.controller.main',{
    extend:'Ext.app.Controller',

    views :['MainView','Login'],
    config:
    {
        refs:

         {
    loginform:'#loginform'
             //selector:'#buttonform'
         }

    },
    init: function(){

        this.control({
            'button[action=submitForm]':{
            tap:'submitcontactform'
        }

        });

    },
    submitcontactform :function(btn)
    {
        //console.log('im a function');
        //var form= this.getLoginform();
        var form=btn.up('formpanel');
        form.submit({
            url:'contact.php'
        });
    }
});
```

and my app.js

```
Ext.application({   
    name:'sencha',  
    controllers : ['main'],

    views :['MainView','Login',''],
    //stores: ['presidentstore'],
    //models: ['presidentmodel'],
    launch:function(){  
            Ext.create('sencha.view.MainView');
                //Ext.Viewport.add({
                //  xclass:'sencha.view.presidentlist'
                //});

    }   

});
```

Comment: How are you getting this form? Are you referencing it correctly within your controller? This might be helpful: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?185671-Uncaught-TypeError-Object-object-Object-has-no-method-getContactForm/page2

Comment: @cclerville thank you . I saw the link but it didnt help me with my problem.and now its showing like this  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of undefined .any ideas...

Comment: Can you show us your controllers config and login form class so that we are sure you are using correct selector?

Comment: i have added my codes above for your reference.any ideas .thank u

Comment: @ram Check my answer. Did you end up solving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your `LoginPanel` has an issue. Your `id` should be inside your `config`. That being said, I would recommend using an `itemId` instead. Your `LoginPanel` should look something like this:

```
Ext.define('sencha.view.Login',{
        extend:'Ext.Panel',
        xtype:'LoginPanel',
        config:{
            title:'LoginForm',
            itemId: 'loginform',
            items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'emailfield',
                        name : 'email',
                        label: 'Email'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        name : 'password',
                        label: 'Password'
                    },
                    {   
                        xtype:'button',
                        text:'Submit',
                        ui:'confirm',
                        action:'submitForm'
                   }
              ]
        }
});
```

Lastly, your controller should look something like this:

```
...
config:{
    refs:{
        loginform:{
            autoCreate: true,
            selector:'#loginform',
            xtype: 'LoginPanel'
        }
    },

    control : {
        'button[action=submitForm]' : {
            tap : "submitcontactform"
        }
    },
},

submitcontactform :function(btn) {
    //console.log('im a function');
    var form= this.getLoginform();
    form.submit({
        url:'contact.php'
    });
}
...
```